# jQuery to GWT - increase and decrease font-size in a whole page

Tags: jquery, gwt

I have one script which reduce and increase the font size of a body content in an HTML page.

I want to do the same things but in a GWT java project.

Here the jQuery code:

```
            $('#agrandir').click(function () {
                    $('body').stop().animate({fontSize: '+=1px'},300);
            });
            $('#diminuer').click(function () {
                    $('body').stop().animate({fontSize: '-=1px'},300);
            });
```

HTML code:

```
      <button id="diminuer">-</button>&nbsp;<button id="agrandir">+</button><br/>
```

Do you know if it's possible to do the same things in GWT?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with [gwtquery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery)

> **Introduction**
>
> GwtQuery a.k.a. GQuery is a jQuery-like API written in GWT, which
>   allows GWT to be used in progressive enhancement scenarios where
>   perhaps GWT widgets are too heavyweight. It can also be used to find
>   and improve your GWT widgets.
>
> GwtQuery is easy to learn for those using jQuery as they share the
>   same api, aditionally gquery adds nice features like type-safe css,
>   compile time optimisations, etc.
>
> Currently, almost the jQuery API is written and all CSS3 selectors
>   should be supported. If you found anything unsupported or not
>   implemented yet, please open an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you can port any jquery code in GWT by using GwtQuery

```
import static com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery.$;
import static com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery.body;
//...

$("#agrandir").click(new Function () {
      public void f(){
          $(body).stop().animate("{fontSize: '+=1px'}",300);
       }
});
$("#diminuer").click(new Function () {
      public void f(){
           $(body).stop().animate("{fontSize: '-=1px'}",300);
       }
});
```

You have just to ensure that the element 9with ids 'agrandir' and 'diminuer') are attached to the dom when you query them